# Can I define the duration of a spot request for instances launching in an AWS Autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

When I define a spot request for an EC2 instance, can I define the duration that I will lease that instance for (e.g. between 1 to 6 hours)?  I can't find a way to do it in an autoscaling group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, after reading the documentation ([cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html), [cfn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-spotprice)) I'm pretty sure there isn't any support for specifying spot instance duration in a launch configuration at this time.